# ¿Cómo obtener información de varios XML contenidos en una carpeta de archivos?

Tags: java

ya tengo un código para obtener información especifica de un XML, sin embargo necesito obtener información de muchos XML almacenados en una carpeta de archivos.El número de archivos puede variar, pero necesito que lo hago con varios archivos. He estado buscando como resolverlo pero no he encontrado algo,agradeceria mucho que me ayuden

A continuación les dejo el codigo que tengo para obtener información de un xml.

```
public static void main (String[]args){
    try{
    DocumentBuilderFactory db= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    //Agilizar la lectura de arhivos grandes
    db.setNamespaceAware(false);
    db.setValidating(false);
    db.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false);
    db.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);
    db.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-dtd-grammar", false);
    db.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
    //Constructor de Objetos
    DocumentBuilder a= db.newDocumentBuilder();
    //Ruta del Archivo
    String archivo="C:\\Users\\carme\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\Documentos\\NetBeansProjects\\Practicarxml\\src\\main\\java\\LeerXml\\1b254147-26f4-4ca9-8f85-3d5da753dc99.xml";
    File f=new File(archivo);    
    //Objeto Documento XML
    Document doc= a.parse(f);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    
    XPath x= XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String Tras="/Comprobante/Impuestos/Traslados/Traslado";
    
    NodeList n=(NodeList)x.compile(Tras).evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
        System.out.println("Cantidad de elementos que empatan con la ruta " + n.getLength());
        Element e= (Element)n.item(0);
        System.out.println("Importe\t\t: " + e.getAttribute("Importe"));
         System.out.println("TasaOCuota\t\t: " + e.getAttribute("TasaOCuota"));
          System.out.println("TipoFactor\t\t: " + e.getAttribute("TipoFactor"));
           System.out.println("Impuesto\t\t: " + e.getAttribute("Impuesto"));
           
           String Con="/Comprobante/Conceptos/Concepto";
           NodeList nodeC=(NodeList)x.compile(Con).evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
           System.out.println("Cantidad de Conceptos de la Factura");
           System.out.println(nodeC.getLength());
           System.out.println( "" );
           
           for (int i = 0; i < nodeC.getLength(); i++) {
            Node nodo= nodeC.item(i);
            if(nodo.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                Element s= (Element)nodo;
                System.out.println("ClaveProdServ\t\t: " + s.getAttribute("ClaveProdServ"));
                System.out.println("ClaveUnidad\t\t: " + s.getAttribute("ClaveUnidad"));
                System.out.println("Descripciont\t\t: " + s.getAttribute("Descripcion"));
                System.out.println("ValorUnitario\t\t: " + s.getAttribute("ValorUnitario"));
                System.out.println("NoIdentificacion\t: " + s.getAttribute("NoIdentificacion"));
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
        }  
    }catch(IOException | ParserConfigurationException | XPathExpressionException | SAXException e){
      Logger.getLogger(Interpretarxml.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);  
    }
}
```

}